# ForeignId Laravel with different type of categories

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I have an item table, each item can have different types of categories.

##### Items

```
Schema::create('cocktails', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Main data
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 30)->unique();
    $table->string('image', 30)
        ->unique()
        ->nullable();

    // Classification       
    $table->foreignId('family_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('glass_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('quantity_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('time_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
});
```

##### Categories

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 30)->unique();
    $table->string('image', 30)
        ->unique()
        ->nullable();

    // Relationships
    $table->string('category_type'); 
});
```

##### Item models

```
Class Cocktail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // Cocktail family
    public function family(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'family_id');
    }

    // Cocktail glasses
    public function glass(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'glass_id');
    }

    // Cocktail quantity
    public function quantity(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'quantity_id');
    }

    // Time quantity
    public function time(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'time_id');
    }
}
```

What is the model for categories?

Comment: You may want to read the documentation on [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations). Your database structure is not correct. And it's possible you'll be unable to rely on the `foreignId()` method in your migration to figure out the correct table and column. You might have to do it manually.